# SIGSEGV (Segmentation fault) when passing a structure to callback in C

Tags: c, segmentation-fault

I got some strange behavior of my code.
I can`t pass a structure to the callback function.

```
#include <malloc.h>
#include "stdint.h"

typedef struct {
    int test_rssi;
    int setup_rssi;
} test_setup_scan_result;

typedef void (*WifiCallback)(uint8_t);

WifiCallback TestSetupCb;

void resume_configuration(test_setup_scan_result *result) {
    if (result == NULL) {
        printf("result is NULL\n");
        return;
    }

    printf("result is not NULL\n");
    printf("setup_rssi %d\n", result->setup_rssi);
    printf("test_rssi %d\n", result->test_rssi);
    printf("done");
}

void scan_test_setup_done_cb() {
    printf("scan_done\n");
    test_setup_scan_result *scan_result = malloc(sizeof(test_setup_scan_result));
    printf("created structure\n");
    scan_result->test_rssi = 1;
    scan_result->setup_rssi = 1;
    printf("filled structure\n");
    if (TestSetupCb) {
        printf("executing cb\n");
        printf("setup_rssi %d\n", scan_result->setup_rssi);
        printf("test_rssi %d\n", scan_result->test_rssi);
        TestSetupCb((uint8_t) scan_result);
    }
}

void scan_for_test_setup(WifiCallback cb) {
    TestSetupCb = cb;
    scan_test_setup_done_cb();
}

int main(void) {
    printf("Hello World\n");
    scan_for_test_setup((WifiCallback)resume_configuration);
    return 0;
}
```

The code after I am trying to get values of the structure in `resume_configuration` function just not works. I am the newbie in c language so any links to useful articles are regarded.

Comment: You can’t cast a pointer to a `uint8_t`. Maybe you meant to use a `uint8_t *` ?

Comment: First observation is that you need `#include <stdio.h>` and unless you have a local version of `stdint` you need `#include <stdint.h>` instead of `#include "stdint.h"`.

Comment: Stop using casts as a quick fix to get the compiler to stop complaining.  Only do it when necessary **and** you can explain why it's necessary.

Comment: @WeatherVane For some reason my compiler doesn't complain about the includes. But I did get: warning: cast from pointer to integer of different size [-Wpointer-to-int-cast]

Comment: @PaulStelian the compiler *should* complain about the lack of `stdio.h` and in the case of `#include "stdint.h"` it is not an error, but unnecessary to look for a `stdint.h` locally before looking in the library headers folder.

Comment: @WeatherVane I think mine would only complain if I actually enabled all warnings with -Wall (or that stdio.h is somehow directly included by malloc.h?)

Comment: If library headers include other headers, there will be a header guard or a pragma to prevent multiple definitions. Make no assumptions about library dependencies and include the headers for the functions you use. And do enable all warnings.

Answer (score 1):

Casting a function name to a function pointer type with incompatible parameter types is *undefined behavior*:

```
scan_for_test_setup((WifiCallback)resume_configuration);
//                  ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
//               Undefined behavior
```

This by itself is enough to get a crash. However, your program does another thing illegally - the call below

```
TestSetupCb((uint8_t) scan_result);
//                    ^^^^^^^^^^^
//               Does not fit in uint8_t
```

would fail regardless of the function pointer cast, because a pointer does not fit in 8 bits.

Comment: On my system in particular the cast of the function pointer works because the function still has one parameter which is passed identically (as a 4-byte value on the stack on Intel 32-bit or as the rsi [I think?] register on Intel 64-bit)

Answer (score 1):

The variable “scan_result” is pointer to struct with allocated memory space in heap region.
When the TestSetupCb() is called with argument “(uint8_t) scan_result” you actually casting address of “scan_result” to be uint8_t, which means to take a first byte of the address and pass it by value. In that case you lose data that you want process in resume_configuration() function.
For example: let’s say the “scan_result” struct it at address “0x004EE388” when you casting this address to uint8_t the result is “0x00000088” this address is invalid and creates issue in your program. Also, this kind of operation creates dangerous to your program.
To solve your problem just re-define function pointer in the following way:
typedef void(*WifiCallback)( test_setup_scan_result *);
and update your code: instead of TestSetupCb((uint8_t)scan_result); change to TestSetupCb(scan_result);

Answer (score 0):

I have run it in Valgrind and I have identified a blatant error (which manifests in several places):

`resume_configuration` does not obey the `WifiCallback` pointer type; it takes a parameter of pointer type, not of `uint8_t` type which most likely has a different size (and it indeed has)

You call `TestSetupCb((uint8_t) scan_result);` -- you explicitly convert the `scan_result` pointer to a datatype smaller than a pointer. You have truncated a pointer, so now the result cannot be converted back into a valid pointer. The truncation on Intel systems is so bad, any resulting pointer will always be in the NULL page.